# formatting returned data in json with php

Tags: php, json

i'm pulling data from a web API which returns the data like this

```
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Puru Farms",
        "Farm_Size": "24 acres",
        "Town": "Dansoman",
        "Farm_Owner_ID": 6,
        "Route_ID": 1,
        "Region_ID": 1,
        "District_ID": 9
    }
]
```

but i want the data to be returned in this format

```
{"data":
[
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "Puru Farms",
        "Farm_Size": "24 acres",
        "Town": "Dansoman",
        "Farm_Owner_ID": 6,
        "Route_ID": 1,
        "Region_ID": 1,
        "District_ID": 9
    }
]}
```

From the API i return the records with this `echo json_encode($data);`

Comment: Well then, wrap another `['data' => $data]` around it…!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return your json data like this:-

```
   json_encode(['data' => $data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

replace your

```
json_encode($data)
```

with

```
$newdata["data"] = $data;
json_encode($newdata);
```